# Serialize MethodInfo in .NET Standard/Core

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I am porting a library from .NET Framework to .NET Standard 2.0. The initial library used the BinaryFormatter to serialize objects of type MethodInfo. While this works without any issues in .NET Framework, with .NET Standard an exception is thrown:

*System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.*

Why isn't this working in .NET Standard/Core? Are there any workarounds to make this possible? I tried to use Newtonsoft to serialize as JSON but then I cannot deserialize it plus that the serialized object ends up taking a lot of memory...

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: and why you wana serialize `RuntimeMethodInfo`?

Comment: We have two systems that share the same library where the first system tells the second system to invoke a method. With the .NET Framework library the invocation is simply done by passing an Expression from which the MethodInfo is serialized and sent over to the second system for execution... We now have a third system which is .NET Core where we need to do the same thing

Comment: then why you dont use own class which would contain Assemby name, Type name and Method name? "second system" can recreate `RuntimeMethodInfo` fom such info ... with some caching should be fine

Comment: good point, will give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

As the exception said, MethodInfo is no longer Serializeable, so you cant serialize delegates, Actions<>, Func<> .... with the default BinarySerializer.

See this issue for more details and the reason: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19119

maybe this helps as a workaround, it uses reflection to bind the function after serializiation:

```
class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Test
    { 

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Action<string> AFunc { get; set; }

        public string[] AFuncIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Methods
    {
        public static void Log(string additional)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(additional);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myTest = new Test();
        myTest.AFunc = Methods.Log;
        myTest.AFuncIdentifier = new string[] { myTest.AFunc.Method.DeclaringType.FullName,
            myTest.AFunc.Method.Name };

        var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myTest);
        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(raw);

        RestoreFunc(test);
        test.AFunc("a");
    }

    private static void RestoreFunc(Test test)
    {
        var fIdentifier = test.AFuncIdentifier;
        var t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(fIdentifier[0]);
        var m = t.GetMethod(fIdentifier[1]);
        test.AFunc = (Action<string>)m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>));
    }
}
```